# Getting StaleElementReferenceException when iterating through a list of WebElements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, staleelementreferenceexception

I was trying to automate the following scenario:

- go to amazon.com
- search for headphones
- add all the bestsellers in the first results page to the cart

The steps I've followed to script this scenario:

- go to amazon.com
- enter the text "headphones" in the search field
- click on search button
- click on a link that is tagged as 'bestseller'
- click on 'add to cart' button
- navigate back to the results page
- click on another link that is tagged as 'bestseller'
- click on 'add to cart' button
- navigate back to the results page

All the bestsellers has the same xpath:

```
//span[.='Best Seller']/../../../../../../../../following-sibling::div/div/following-sibling::div/div/div/div/div/div/h2/a/span
```

So I've implemented this a list of WebElements as follows:

```
List<WebElement> bestsellers = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath of bestsellers"));
```

I've implemented the clicking on a link and adding to  the cart using loop  in 3 ways as follows:

```
for(WebElement product: bestsellers) {
    product.click();
    clickOnAddToCartButton();
    driver.navigate().back();
}



for(int i=0; i<bestsellers.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(bestsellers.size());
        bestsellers.get(i).click();
        clickOnAddToCartButton();
        driver.navigate().back();

    }



Iterator<WebElement> i = bestsellers.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        WebElement product = i.next();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(product));

        product.click();
        clickOnAddToCartButton();
        driver.navigate().back();
    }
```

There are 3 elements in the list 'bestsellers' When I had run the script. When the loop is executed, the first element is getting clicked and added to the cart and the driver navigates back to the results page. Then I'm getting   staleElementReferenceException using the above 3 ways.

Update:
I've implemented the scenario as  follows:

```
for(int i=0; i<bestsellers.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println("Current :" + i);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//span[.='Best Seller']/../../../../../../../../following-sibling::div/div/following-sibling::div/div/div/div/div/div/h2/a/span")));
        driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//span[.='Best Seller']/../../../../../../../../following-sibling::div/div/following-sibling::div/div/div/div/div/div/h2/a/span")).get(i).click();
        clickOnAddToCartButton();
        //clickOnViewCart();
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(cartButton));
        }catch(TimeoutException e) {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(viewCartButton));
        }
        if(i==(bestsellers.size()-1)) {
            try {
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(cartButton));    
                cartButton.click();
                break;
            }catch(TimeoutException e) {
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(viewCartButton));    
                viewCartButton.click();
                break;
            }
        }

        driver.navigate().back();
```

Comment: driver.navigate().back();  - This will refresh the elements on the page which is causing this staleElementReferenceException.

Comment: ok. thanks for the info. Could you please suggest me a workaround?

Comment: Should I open the link new tab and close the tab when I'm done with it?

Comment: In this way, I can come back to the results page without refreshing the elements.

Comment: you might consider storing the hrefs (url to the individual product) in a list and then navigate to the hrefs, click add to cart, navigate the the next href, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you click on the element or back() in the browser the element reference will updated in the selenium so you can not point to the elements with the old references and which led to the `StatleElementException`.

Consider this approach when you have to iterate through multiple elements interaction.

```
List<WebElement> bestsellers = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath of bestsellers"));
for(int i=0; i<bestsellers.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Current Seller " + i);
    // here you are getting the elements each time you iterate, which will get the
    // latest element references
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath of bestsellers")).get(i).click();
    clickOnAddToCartButton();
    driver.navigate().back();

}
```

Comment: Tried the above code. Only 2 bestseller items are added to the cart when there are 4 bestsellers in the page. It is going to all the 4 bestseller products pages but only 2 are being added to the cart.

Comment: Try with ` driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath of bestsellers")).get(0).click();` just replace `i` with `0` so that always the first item will be added.

Comment: No I want to add all the bestseller items in the first page.

Comment: After the 'add to cart' is clicked, 'go to cart' and 'Proceed to check out' options are displayed. I've waited for them to confirm the 'add to cart' is clicked otherwise I get to know the problem. It worked. I've updated the code in the question